# Как сервисы определяют возраст конкретной страницы в Яндексе?

Tags: поиск-api

Есть ряд сервисов по определению возраста конкретной страницы сайта, например https://be1.ru/vozrast-stranicy/ или https://almost.ru/age-yandex/ или другой... Указываешь им список страниц, а они тебе выдают даты, когда эти страницы были проиндексированы Яндексом. Вопрос: это у Яндекса есть какое-то API для этого или парсят вывод какого-то запроса в поисковую строку Яндекса?

Раньше это выводилось путем добавления параметра how=tm в запрос, но этот функционал в Яше прикрыли. Как же теперь это определяется?